# Some mistake in calling one procedure from another

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Due to a requirement I have to call one stored procedure from another.

The problem seems to be somewhere around the output parameter `out_result_size`, which I am using. When I test `main_func` it works fine but when I test `synonym_proc` it says

> synonym_proc is invalid

I have to, ultimately, call `synonym_proc` from Java using JPA's `@NamedNativeQuery`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE synonym_proc (
    result_cursor      OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
    in_cp_id           IN NUMBER,
    in_cp_name         IN VARCHAR2 := NULL,
    in_country_name    IN VARCHAR2 := NULL,
    in_industry_name   IN VARCHAR2 := NULL,
    in_max_result_size IN NUMBER
) AS
    out_result_size NUMBER;
BEGIN
   result_cursor := someSchema.somePackage.main_func(in_cp_id,
              in_cp_name,
              in_country_name,
              in_industry_name,
              in_max_result_size,
              out_result_size);
END;
```

**UPDATE:** Apologies for not mentioning the changes in the question which I didn't notice earlier. The `main_func` is a function (not procedure), which returns a cursor and resides inside some package which is in some schema. When I compile I get the following compilation errors:

> Error: PLS-00201: identifier 'SOMESCHEMA.SOMEPACKAGE' must be
>   declared.. statement ignored.

**Update 2**

SomeSchema definition

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE someSchema."SomePackage"
is
...
function mainFunc
(
    in_cp_id                in gem.tcp_real_profile_main_approved.cp%type
    , in_cp_name            in gem.tcp_real_profile_main_approved.name%type
    , in_country_name       in gem.tcp_real_profile_main_approved.country_name%type
    , in_industry_name      in gem.tcp_real_profile_main_approved.industry_name%type
    , in_max_result_size    in number
    , out_result_size       out number
)
return search_result_type_cursor;
```

**ADDED**

```
type search_result_type_cursor
 is ref cursor
 return search_type;
```

And yes the datatypes are correct since I described the function (main_func) and cross verified the datatypes.

Comment: yes, it is invalid.  what do you get when you actually try to compile this procedure?

Comment: I mentioned it in the question. "Error: PLS-00201: identifier 'SOMESCHEMA.SOMEPACKAGE' must be declared.. statement ignored."

Comment: and what is the definition of someSchema.somePackage.main_func?

Comment: @tbone, pls see Update 2

Comment: You're mixing a `sys_refcursor` with what is presumably a strongly-typed `search_result_type_cursor`. Is that intentional, or necessary?

Comment: I'll just assume that the data types used to call the function are correct (eg, that "gem.tcp_real_profile_main_approved.cp%type is in fact a number, etc.).  And not sure how search_result_type_cursor is defined either

Comment: can you describe someschema.somepackage when logged in as the user who is trying to create "synonym_proc"?

Comment: @Alex, have mentioned search_result_type_cursor definition. Don't have much idea about cursors.

Comment: Yes @tbone I already described by right clicking in my SQl*Developer. Datatypes are correct and matched. Pls see the Added part.

Comment: are you compiling "synonym_proc" as the same user as created someschema.somepackage?

Comment: NO I have not much idea about the someSchema.somePackage. That is provided by business. I am compiling synonym_proc as another user. But am able to describe and test the main_func.

Comment: Are your privileges on `someSchema.somePackage` granted via a role? Such privs are not available within a stored procedure (see [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e16543/authorization.htm#sthref547), or [this TechRepublic explanation](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/understanding-roles-in-oracle-stored-procedures/6183799)); you'd need to have the privileges granted directly to the user creating the procedure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments, particularly that you can describe and test the procedure in the other schema, it looks like this may be a permission issue. If your privileges on the objects in the other schema are granted via a role then you will be able to execute the package procedure directly, but roles [aren't recognised inside named blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e16543/authorization.htm#sthref547). If this is the issue then you will have to get execute permission on `someSchema.somePackage` granted directly to the user that is creating the stored procedure.

To demonstrate the issue, I can create a package in my `SCOTT` schema and grant execute on it to a role, and grant that role to a user - both of which I've created for the test. As `SYS`:

```
create role scott_tmp_role;
grant connect to someuser identified by <password>;
grant scott_tmp_role to someuser;
grant create procedure to someuser;
```

As `SCOTT`:

```
create package p42 as
    procedure proc;
end p42;
/

Package created.

create package body p42 as
    procedure proc is
    begin
        null;
    end proc;
end p42;
/

Package body created.

grant execute on p42 to scott_tmp_role;

Grant succeeded.
```

As my new `SOMEUSER`, verify the roles I have:

```
select * from session_roles;

ROLE
------------------------------
CONNECT
SCOTT_TMP_ROLE
```

I can execute the procedure in an anonymous block:

```
begin
    scott.p42.proc;
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

... but not in a named block:

```
create or replace procedure sp42 as
begin
    scott.p42.proc;
end;
/

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

show errors

Errors for PROCEDURE SP42:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
3/2      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
3/2      PLS-00201: identifier 'SCOTT.P42' must be declared
```

If `SCOTT` grants the permission directly to my new user:

```
grant execute on p42 to someuser;
```

... then the named block now works:

```
create or replace procedure sp42 as
begin
    scott.p42.proc;
end;
/

Procedure created.
```

If you want to see where you might be getting the execute permission from, you can run a query like this, although there may be a hierarchy of roles to pick through:

```
select grantee, privilege from all_tab_privs
where table_schema = 'SomeSchema'
and table_name = 'SomePackage';
```

Comment: One of the best explained answers seen in SO. Your reason is absolutely correct (although it is another thing that the package on we need access is very crucial and we are finding ways to do it). +1 for the nice explanation. Thanks Alex!

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify the size of parameters for a procedure or function. Try removing the sizes, as well as moving the `commit` as Vincent suggested.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE synonym_proc(result_cursor      OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
                                         in_cp_id           IN NUMBER,
                                         in_cp_name         IN VARCHAR2,
                                         in_country_name    IN VARCHAR2,
                                         in_industry_name   IN VARCHAR2,
                                         in_max_result_size IN NUMBER) AS
  out_result_size NUMBER;
BEGIN
  main_proc(result_cursor,
            in_cp_id,
            in_cp_name,
            in_country_name,
            in_industry_name,
            in_max_result_size,
            out_result_size);
  COMMIT;
END;
```

You should be getting an error like `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following: ...`

Comment: Thanks for the answer Alex. But thats not the main reason. I updated question. My Bad. Kindly see the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for Oracle SP is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procedure_name(--parameter list) AS
--Local Variables
BEGIN
--Body
END;
```

Now you have made a mistake that instead of putting COMMIT before END you have placed it after END. It should be like this

```
COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Zeeshan. But thats not the main reason. I updated question. My Bad. Kindly see the updated question.